# catalyst consistent url format with trailing slash

Tags: perl, url, catalyst, trailing-slash

I'm developing a [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org) application and having trouble with the way `Catalyst` interprets urls.

Let's say that in our Catalyst application we have a controller `Account`. If this is the case, Catalyst will interpret

> `http://mydomain.com/account`  and  `http://mydomain.com/account/`

as the same url for the **index** action.

However, for SEO and linking purposes (and just to be consistent overall) I would like to force Catalyst to only recognize one format and stick to it.

I've found one module that seems to be built for this: [Catalyst::Plugin::SanitizeUrl](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aSanitizeUrl), it's documentation says you should just put

> use Catalyst 'SanitizeUrl';

in `myapp.pm` and this will handle everything for you.

However, whenever I use it I just get this **error:**

```
Bad request
```

On every page load. Does anyone know of a simple way to have Catalyst only use one format?

Comment: Bad request with trailing slash, without, or both ways?

Comment: both ways. It seems there was actually a bug report about it here: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=72399

Comment: An alternate module is listed in that bug report.

Comment: I tried that module and it actually had no effect on my urls (with or without slash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up combining what edem said with some stuff that I did and this is my end result:

```
sub begin :Private {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    #don't allow trailing slashes!
    my @path = split "/", $c->req->path, -1;
    if(@path and (pop @path eq '')) {
        my $p = join '/', @path;
        #set as moved permanently
        $c->res->redirect("/$p", 301);
        return;
    }
}
```

If there is a trailing slash at the end of the request, it will always redirect to the same url but without the slash.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to force Catalyst use only one format without trailing slash is add this method to MyApp.pm:

```
sub begin :Private {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    my @path = split "/", $c->req->path, -1;
    $c->detach('default') if @path and (pop @path eq '');
}
```

It will redirect on 'default' method a.k.a Page 404 if uri ends with slash on any request.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can forward url to different action method depending on whether trailing `/` is present or not.
So,

```
sub index :Path :Args(0) { 
    my ($self,$c) = @_;
    my $path = $c->request->path;
    my $matched = $path =~ s/(\/)$//;
    if ($matched) {
          $c->forward('withslash');
    }
    else {
          $c->forward('withoutslash');
    }
}
```

Again this is an untried solution, you might need to check it.